# insertAfter creates empty space but doesn't insert element

Tags: jquery

I want to insert a elements dynamically in between two elements. When I do with `insertAfter()` function it inserts for only once between elements and doesn't insert the element on other places But it creates a empty space between the elements where the element has to be inserted.

```
<div id = "icons">
<a class = "favorite" data-value = "{{$candidate->id}}" > <img id = "no_p_fav" src="{{url('/icons/non_star.png')}}" ></img></a>
</div>
```

Here is how i insert the element dynamically

```
function updatePriority(candidate_id,msg){

if (msg == "pre")//apply prioritized property to the card 
{
    $('.favorite[data-value='+candidate_id+'] img#no_p_fav').attr('id','fav');

    $( '<a class = "prioritize" data-value = "'+candidate_id+'"><img id = '+
     '"priority" src="/icons/priority.png"></img></a> ').insertAfter('.favorite[data-value='+candidate_id+'] img#fav');

}
```

The above function is called from the `ajax` success method, and arguments passed to this method are from `ajax response`.

Comment: You say "doesn't insert the element on other places". It's not completely clear from the wording, but are you saying that the element should be inserted into multiple places simultaneously? If so that is not possible, because you are telling it to insert only after an element with a specific ID.

Comment: Missing } in final function for close it.

Comment: i want to insert only after a element with particular id , when i do it it gets added without any issue only on one element. when i do the same on other elements, an empty space is created without inserting the element

Comment: but ID's can't be repeated so problem likely lies elsewhere....provide a demo that reproduces problem as per [mcve]

Comment: please show an example of "when i do the same on other elements" where it fails.

Comment: @yes i was making this mistake , instead of using `img#fav` i changed it to `img`. Thank you @charlietfl